# Existence of left limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have a real-valued single-variable cadlag function $f$. I also have an increasing sequence of bounded real numbers $(t_k)_k$ that converges to some finite limit, say $t$. By the existence of left limits of $f$, I have $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(t_k) =: f(t-) < \infty$.

What I would like to know is how this property contradicts the statement
$$\lvert f(t_k) - f(t_k-)\rvert \geq \varepsilon \qquad k = 0,1,\ldots$$
where $f(t_k-) := \lim_{s\uparrow t_k} f(s)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.

By the existence of the left limit, I can write 
$$\lvert f(t_k) - f(t_-)\rvert < \varepsilon $$
for all $k\geq N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

This seems like a contradiction to the statement above but I don't have the actual argument to show that.

Comment: What if the function is continuous? It possesses left limits everywhere, but $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$, or in other words, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$ for $x$ close enough to $x_0$.

Comment: @Clayton By a similar argument $\lvert f(t_k) - f(t-) \rvert < \varepsilon $ for $k\geq N$ for some $N$. I played around with this but couldn't get to a contradiction. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that what you were seeking? A function that has left limits everywhere, but such that there does **not** exist an $\varepsilon>0$ with $|f(t_k)-f(t-)|\geq\varepsilon$?

Comment: @Clayton No, the other statement is about the jump size at each $t_k$.

Comment: I am not sure your question is worded well, then. Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: @Clayton I edited the question. Is what I am trying to show clearer now?

Comment: Not so much. Are you wondering why: $$\lim_{k\to\infty} f(t_k)=f(t_k^-)<\infty\not\Rightarrow|f(t_k)-f(t_k^-)|\geq\varepsilon$$for some given $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: @Clayton Almost. I am wondering why $\lvert f(t_k) - f(t_k-) \rvert \geq \varepsilon$ implies that limit being finite cannot be true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73437/discussion-between-clayton-and-calculon).